# How to union two collections without overriding any value

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am trying to get the union of two collections without overriding any value:

First Collection:

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array [▼
    0 => array [▼
      "status" => "Invoice"
      "letterPaymentAmount" => 4240.0
      "BankAccountNo" => "SEK"
      "Date" => "2017-07-15T16:32:22"
      "DueDate" => "2017-07-28T00:00:00"
      "ocr" => "3000000202"
      "lastDatePayDay" => "28"
   ]]}
```

Second Collection

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array [▼
    0 => array [▼
  "status": "Reminder",
  "letterPaymentAmount": 4300,
  "BankAccountNo": "SEK",
  "Date": "2017-08-15T16:01:30",
  "DueDate": "2017-08-30T00:00:00",
  "ocr": "3000002406",
  "lastDatePayDay": "30",
  "lastDatePayMonth": "Aug",
  "Country": "Singapore",
  "Customer": "TickTack"  
   ]]}
```

I want to acomplish this:

```
Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array [▼
    0 => array [▼
      "status" => "Invoice"
      "letterPaymentAmount" => 4240.0
      "BankAccountNo" => "SEK"
      "Date" => "2017-07-15T16:32:22"
      "DueDate" => "2017-07-28T00:00:00"
      "ocr" => "3000000202"
      "lastDatePayDay" => "28"],
    1=> [     
      "status": "Reminder",
      "letterPaymentAmount": 4300,
      "BankAccountNo": "SEK",
      "Date": "2017-08-15T16:01:30",
      "DueDate": "2017-08-30T00:00:00",
      "ocr": "3000002406",
      "lastDatePayDay": "30",
      "lastDatePayMonth": "Aug",
      "Country": "Singapore",
      "Customer": "TickTack"  ]]}
```

I do not want to override any existing key or value just add them together.

I have tried `union()` but that overrides the existing keys and does not take keys that do not exist in first collection .

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 9):

Have you used [`concat()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-concat)? An example is the following:

```
    $col1 = collect([
        ['abc' => 1, 'dec' => 2],
        ['abc' => 1, 'dec' => 6]
    ]);
    $col2 = collect([
        ['abc' => 3, 'dec' => 4, 'acd' => 2],
        ['abc' => 1, 'dec' => 8, 'acd' => 6],
    ]);

    return $col1->concat($col2);
```

> Note: if you use this on a collection without nested array then you might get different result from this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`push`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-push) to add new items to an existing collection without editing items.

```
$collection = collect([['a' => 'b']]);
$collection2 = collect([['c' => 'd']]);
$collection2->each(function ($e) use (&$collection) {
    $collection->push($e);
});
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I get still only $collection 2, merge is working actually! But I was trying ur way also coud''t make it work

Comment: But the result of my code would be in the variable `$collection`.

Answer (score -3):

Use [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-merge)

```
$first = collect(['One','Two']);

$second = collect(['Two','Five']);

$merged = $first->merge($second);

// $merged->all();
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. From the very documentation you linked: `If a string key in the given items matches a string key in the original collection, the given items's value will overwrite the value in the original collection`